# is it possible to replace a template variable in all img paths on a site with a set value from inside .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, path

I have a template page and want to replace my placeholder "variable" used in the path of all src="" and href="" on the page.

Paths look like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/VARIABLE/custom.css" />
 <img src="http://somewhere.com/VARIABLE/img/1.jpg" />
```

which I want to change to:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/set-value/custom.css" />
 <img src="http://somewhere.com/set-value/img/1.jpg" />
```

I first tried this with javascript/jquery client side, but I can't get it to work properly.

So I'm wondering whether this is something I can do in .htaccess? I'm a total .htaccess newbie, so some pointers on where to start would also be appreciated.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is it a PHP page? Is it a server-side template (what engine)?

Comment: hm. I think it can run php, but right now it's just a static mockup page, without any server-side templating or engine. I had planned to set a cookie with the set-value and replace all paths on a page with the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
RewriteRule  ^/var1/(.+)$                 /value1/$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^/var2/(.+)$                 /value2/$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^/var3/(.+)$                 /value3/$1 [L]
# ...
```

But I'm pretty sure there are better ways to accomplish your goal. Why do you need this, what are you trying to do?

---

**EDIT**

You could use a special php page instead of the "variable", e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/variable.php/css/custom.css" />
<img src="/variable.php/img/1.jpg" />
```

Then in `variable.php` use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to get the trailing path, i.e. `/css/custom.css` or `/img/1.jpg` respectively. Then point to the correct file you want for each client (maybe based on the cookie value?).

Comment: I have a static HTML page, which should be a mock up for clients. Since I don't want to create a mockup for every client, I wanted to set a cookie on the first page with the *save-as* value. On the page there is are a lot of image/css links, which include "variable" in their path. I now want to replace "variable" with the cookie-saved set-value. This way I only need to create the images and folders and a have a working demo customized for every client

Comment: I don't think `.htaccess` is the way to go here. See my editted answer for a different option.

Comment: this also sounds good. Trying to try both variations. Thx so far!